# How to add Amount Column of JTable and Display in JTextField outside the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add all the values of amount column and show in the total amount field.
**Here's my code**

```
public int getSum()
    {
        int rowsCount = jTable1.getRowCount();
        int sum =0;
        for (int  i=0; i<rowsCount; i++)
        {
            sum = sum+Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

And Where to  call this getSum().In **ActionPerformed** of TextField or In **Constructor.**
***Note : Whenever i put values in Amount Column it automatically get added/reflect in Total amount*** 
[Here's my screen shot of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vONWM.png)

Comment: after this code 'sum = sum+Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());'  try add this : textfield.setText(""+sum);

Answer (score 0):

`getSum()` should be called in the `setText` of the text field:

```
tf.setText("" + getSum())
```

because the sum should be what is displayed in the text field - its text. Now whenever you put t he values in the amount column call the method I showd.

Comment: this is error am getting Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String:                                                  txt_total.setText(Integer.toString(getSum())); then i use this .still its not working.

Comment: @RahulBhosale Just convert int to String.

Comment: how to convert int to string?@Mark

Comment: thank you  everyone. i got the solution and it's working.

Comment: @RahulBhosale Then please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark icon next to the score. You can also upvote if you want.

Comment: @RahulBhosale There are many ways to convert int to String like concating with `""` or with `String.valueOf` methods. Just google "convert int to String in Java" and you will get 1000 answers.